# Severe problem with back button, Chrome and DOM updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datatables

Ok I have a weird with Chrome(and probably Safari).  I have a table with selected rows and date selector.  If I select the data table rows and change a date then go forward a page and hit the back button then it doesn't take in account of the changes on the page.  It shows the old date and all the old selected rows.

In Firefox and IE it works right.  What is the issue here.  If anybody needs more clarification let me know.

Comment: when you change the date on the first page, are you actually saving data somewhere? If so, Chrome is likely retrieving a cached version of the page, whereas FF/IE are not.

Comment: When the date is selected I am putting it into a cookie.  The date picker is actually a jeditable text field.  When they hit enter it saves.  I click on a page going forward and then hit the back button the old value is there.  I'm retrieving the value from a cookie to populate the text field but that doesn't seem to do anything since the page is cached I guess.

Comment: Since you are retrieving the value from a cookie, you can use that to change the cached data. If you use jquery just get your cookie info from inside `$(function () { })`. This will execute code as soon as the page (and DOM) is completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

Use cache control  'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'

no-cache should do it, but chrome needs no-store, and IE needs must-revalidate.